# Help to understand what's inside base64 string

Tags: python

While performing a file upload, a `template` parameter is sent together with file. Service acts differently when different parameters are passed.
I need help to figure out what this parameter contains.
Here are two examples:

`7b0fc4f83d3fc320ef3865a1b472caeba3f0b60e09f257c61f34af77a7ff57adTB5QO8kXU18KUIgZGXblGYAOC7qbRzizHLGpGdUPbywggHncAkwJVe4M/0w7Dy9svucGrEgYbud0OY5iCFlTalho9j9SWzGMXlWjqU0wrFApBh+/Rqy8v93q1gBlpwLsuj7WBppuWItBmhoOyxkyKLv8Vm6AVVeXxndd4kklq+E=` - allows uploading any file

`8849c262187451b5f558f4c2f150ec67efaafc192f51b1b8983754090e0c767bb+5SL0SVpqqHUB7zPYvNzEMSanK9r2uL7xUe/TK+9rofXD6gqQpsIKB2P7aECihmfEwEdQaLG6Kz3W5B1wiwxZRbdutdBbRYClAAoZ/bhaTdm2VnPBVZKuisi3cVVM91p2/pjb/qSPor7/026fq9PitSBizAtSbf858/BcTu7sw=H2pFMj+uoRaSnqqPdNbdrZzh3AF9H0uhagE9V7R6V8Ed67HFvGYS/Cg9DReGtlj1n1HtjpV14qqfYt5l/tVesG2B/Xh84tkr14t/RgTUA7cXwn3bWEWUcjxCFWlmAs2RXLs6g1Up3e/g4rolmGO8JAbFwRXWhFQQvZMx1+D5tjM=Tie6y7lK/q6Vlw9ssVYUYDP5Il5dYZxGPtkJSkaOPNGjkin81azLZFdtU7K6wUBcHYOoZzhthYdFMIK8K30UMGPMQI9/d4AKJsATT1PXaw/A1bjkMnapCdJl4IWGNs55IgHEs6mMPENlBuVodjQXJNodIkXOFa+I+q+MlGu0Rls=` - allows uploading only images

My guess is that this is a serialized object that contains upload configuration. Are there any ideas how to understand and maybe deserialize these strings?

Comment: The base64 decode is binary that I don't recognize.

Comment: It could be just a string representation of an internal binary object, like a struct...

Answer (score 2):

*Just a brief analyze of data samples you provided.*

- First:
  `7b0fc4f83d3fc320ef3865a1b472caeba3f0b60e09f257c61f34af77a7ff57adTB5QO8kXU18KUIgZGXblGYAOC7qbRzizHLGpGdUPbywggHncAkwJVe4M/0w7Dy9svucGrEgYbud0OY5iCFlTalho9j9SWzGMXlWjqU0wrFApBh+/Rqy8v93q1gBlpwLsuj7WBppuWItBmhoOyxkyKLv8Vm6AVVeXxndd4kklq+E=`
- Second:
  `8849c262187451b5f558f4c2f150ec67efaafc192f51b1b8983754090e0c767bb+5SL0SVpqqHUB7zPYvNzEMSanK9r2uL7xUe/TK+9rofXD6gqQpsIKB2P7aECihmfEwEdQaLG6Kz3W5B1wiwxZRbdutdBbRYClAAoZ/bhaTdm2VnPBVZKuisi3cVVM91p2/pjb/qSPor7/026fq9PitSBizAtSbf858/BcTu7sw=H2pFMj+uoRaSnqqPdNbdrZzh3AF9H0uhagE9V7R6V8Ed67HFvGYS/Cg9DReGtlj1n1HtjpV14qqfYt5l/tVesG2B/Xh84tkr14t/RgTUA7cXwn3bWEWUcjxCFWlmAs2RXLs6g1Up3e/g4rolmGO8JAbFwRXWhFQQvZMx1+D5tjM=Tie6y7lK/q6Vlw9ssVYUYDP5Il5dYZxGPtkJSkaOPNGjkin81azLZFdtU7K6wUBcHYOoZzhthYdFMIK8K30UMGPMQI9/d4AKJsATT1PXaw/A1bjkMnapCdJl4IWGNs55IgHEs6mMPENlBuVodjQXJNodIkXOFa+I+q+MlGu0Rls=`

---

1. First 64 symbols. It could be *sha256* hash of file you upload or key for decryption data which encoded in *base64*;
2. *First* part contains single *base64* which contains **128** bytes of data. *Second* example contains 2 parts encoded in *base64* separately (splitting data into chunks could be caused by limits for data size of selected encrypting algorithm):

   - First part (decoded data length: **256**) 
     `b+5SL0SVpqqHUB7zPYvNzEMSanK9r2uL7xUe/TK+9rofXD6gqQpsIKB2P7aECihmfEwEdQaLG6Kz3W5B1wiwxZRbdutdBbRYClAAoZ/bhaTdm2VnPBVZKuisi3cVVM91p2/pjb/qSPor7/026fq9PitSBizAtSbf858/BcTu7sw=H2pFMj+uoRaSnqqPdNbdrZzh3AF9H0uhagE9V7R6V8Ed67HFvGYS/Cg9DReGtlj1n1HtjpV14qqfYt5l/tVesG2B/Xh84tkr14t/RgTUA7cXwn3bWEWUcjxCFWlmAs2RXLs6g1Up3e/g4rolmGO8JAbFwRXWhFQQvZMx1+D5tjM=`
   - Second part (decoded data length: **128**)
     `Tie6y7lK/q6Vlw9ssVYUYDP5Il5dYZxGPtkJSkaOPNGjkin81azLZFdtU7K6wUBcHYOoZzhthYdFMIK8K30UMGPMQI9/d4AKJsATT1PXaw/A1bjkMnapCdJl4IWGNs55IgHEs6mMPENlBuVodjQXJNodIkXOFa+I+q+MlGu0Rls=`
3. Decoded data of each this parts looks too random, so I suppose that data encoded using one of *block cipher symmetric-key algorithms*. Why? Because:

   - If data is not encoded 99% of developers will use *JSON* or *XML* or whatever else instead of custom structures which means additional work on serializer (all developers are lazy);
   - Length of each block of data is exactly divisible by 16;
   - Weird hash on the start of sample which could be a key or any other input for decryption (length - **64**, btw).

It's all interesting information which can be extracted from your samples. Maybe I noticed something you haven't yet, who knows  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯